# URL Rewrite in IIS 7 causes redirect loop

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have tried various methods found on the web (including some SO answers) for getting URL rewrite in IIS 7  to work so that I can turn mysite.com/somepage.aspx into mysite.com/somepage, for example.  The last thing I've tried is the video at this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBNJE7XA1m0.  After applying these changes in IIS, I now can request mysite.com/somepage and get to mysite.com/somepage.aspx with the .aspx removed in the address bar.  Partial success.

When I try to directly request mysite.com/somepage.aspx, however, I get into a redirect loop.  I am hoping there is some simple mistake in my settings.  Here is the `web.config` section created by making changes in IIS:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="HideAspxExtension">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.aspx" matchType="IsFile" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.aspx" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RedirectingAspxExtension" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*).aspx$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(.*).aspx$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I have tried to apply this setting to multiple applications and I get the same results.  What I do not have is another server to test on.

Answer (score 0):

These are rules I've used before:

```
<rule name="StripAspx">
    <match url="^(.+)\.aspx$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<!-- Rewrite the .aspx for internal processing-->
<rule name="RewriteASPX" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
</rule>
```

The main differences I can see are:

- These have the removal of the `.aspx` first (in rewrite rules, order matters). This also means that in these rules the `stopProcessing` directive is on the rewrite **to** `.aspx`, not the redirect away from it.
- These don't have `<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.aspx" matchType="IsFile" />`